# Raspberry Pi 3 as Wireless Bridge

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, wireless-bridge

Basically I want to set up my RPI3 to be a wireless access bridge. I have Ethernet running to eth0 with a DHCP assigned IP 192.168.1.198, the gateway in my network is an AT&T Router at 192.168.1.254 that does all the DHCP/DNS. I want wireless clients to access my network via wlan0 and be assigned an IP in 192.168.1.0/24 via the router and use the gateway for DNS.

I'm new at this and started looking through this article here:
https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/

It looks like it sets up a static address though at 172.24.1.1 and then runs its own DHCP via dnsmasq in the range of 172.24.1.50 and 172.24.1.150. What would I need to do to tailor it to my requirements?

Comment: Nearly everything except most of hostapd.conf. You will have better luck searching for a tutorial about setting up a bridge in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Your instructions are for setting up a router; 80%–90% of them is useless for a bridge.

Instead:

1. Use the system's network configuration (e.g. /etc/network/interfaces) to set up a basic *Ethernet* bridge (br0), with just a single port (eth0).

   All IP configuration (address, gateway) has to be moved from eth0 itself to the bridge interface.

   ```
   iface br0 inet dhcp
       bridge_ports eth0
       bridge_fd 0
   ```
2. Set up hostapd with the `bridge=br0` option, which tells it to add the AP interface to that bridge.

   You can reuse the hostapd config from other tutorials (even the one you found) as long as it has this setting. For example:

   ```
   driver=nl80211
   interface=wlan0_ap
   bridge=br0

   hw_mode=g
   channel=13

   ssid=YourWiFiName
   wpa=2
   wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
   wpa_passphrase=Somepassphrase
   ```
3. Use `bridge link` or `brctl showstp` to make sure that the bridge now contains two ports; also `iw wlan0_ap station dump` to see connected clients.

Comment: There seemed to be some kernel driver issue on the latest Raspbian Jessie with Pixel Desktop that caused hostapd to not be able to connect devices to the net. I ended up scrapping the idea and got a secondary wireless AP from RadioShack they're closing down and having a big sale. I'm putting Windows IoT Core on this RPI3.